# Can I rely on firebase as database for application android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i have app , i need connect app with database but i dont know if firebase database  good for my app instead of using the server 
please advise about this and what is different both and do i can rely as main database for my app

FYI - phrase my app  shopping online simple

Comment: You can store your data on Firebase Realtime Database as well in your Sqlite local db at the same time as well so as to ensure safety and backup of your data

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  If you have a question that's asking for an opinion, like this one, please post it to a discussion forum, such as [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/).  I think you'll find that this sort of question gets asked a lot, so it might be helpful to search first.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a really nice option for starting as

1. It help new developers with higher compatibility with the app
2. Firebase manages mostly all server side scripting and things you might need in the future
3. It is free for small scale apps and user can choose to pay as they use over the quota

I will suggest you to go for firebase if you are not dealing files (pictures, videos, pdfs, other) as it only offers 5GB cloud storage for free

If your app deals with lots of users and lots of files, firebase will be expensive for you in the long run

Comment: If I choose to pay will I avoid the problem of so many users that no problems happen ؟؟

Comment: this is  5GB cloud storage for free every month ?

Comment: 5 GB free storage in total, and firebase have quota based subscribtion, you can pay per extra GB space you need monthly, if you choose to pay you will have no other problem than expenses